# As a development organization, we'd like to enable transparency of all work being done

Tags: extjs, rally

As a development organization, we'd like to enable transparency of all work being done on our WORKSPACES (X AND Y), so that we can more easily share knowledge across the organization.

All users with current Rally credentials within the X workspace should have viewer rights to the Y workspace (and its projects).  Users who already have editor access in the Y space should be unaffected (not have their permissions adjusted), and there is no need to enable viewer access for disabled users.

Thoughts on the best way to implement something like this in Rally? How can we assign READ ONLY access to thousands of Editors from Workspace X Readonly access to Workspace Y without affecting Editors in Workspace Y?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for some bulk permissioning features built right in the tool.  Is that right?  I'm sure this could be done right now with a script, but it would take a little work...  And would get out of date when projects were added/removed... Seems like you would want a "Workspace Viewer" role to be added?

Comment: Correct. Editors in Workspace X bulk updated to be "Workspace Viewers" in Workspace Y.